# What happen when db version change in Phonegap

Tags: database, cordova

I wanna change db schema of db which already exist. What should i do? Do I have to change db version? Here is an example that [Phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#version) describe.(very short) I did try this but I don't get it. Anyone can give me an example?

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
db.changeVersion("1.0", "1.1");
```